# Argue that no further mixed Nash Equilibria can exists

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, dominant-strategy

I'm looking at the following Normal-Form Game:

```
         B
   |  1  |  2  |  3
---+-----------------
  1| 1,-1|-1, 1|-1, 1
A 2|-1, 1| 2,-2|-1, 1
  3|-1, 1|-1, 1| 3,-3
```

It's easy to see that there are no Nash-Equilibria in pure strategies. In mixed strategies I found, that $(\sigma_A, \sigma_B)$ is a Nash-Equilibrium with:

$$\sigma_A(1) = \sigma_B(1) = \frac{6}{13}$$
$$\sigma_A(2) = \sigma_B(2) = \frac{4}{13}$$
$$\sigma_A(3) = \sigma_B(3) = \frac{3}{13}$$

The problem sheet now asks to argue with an example why no further mixed Nash equilibrium can exist. I'm not sure how to argue here.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know what support sets are? Why are they forcing you to solve game theory exercises during summer?

Comment: @Giskard I never heard of support sets (I don't think they were included in my lecture) and I'm studying for an exam on Thursday.

Comment: Here is the hint that @Giskard was trying to give you on [support sets](http://gametheory101.com/courses/game-theory-101/support-of-mixed-strategies/): "A pure strategy is in the **support of a mixed strategy** if that pure strategy is played with positive probability according to the mixed strategy. If a mixed strategy is played in a Nash equilibrium, all pure strategies in the support of that mixed strategy must yield an equal expected payoff."

Comment: Also see [my answer to a related question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/21557/42).